# How can I retrieve dynamically the duration of an event? (like mouseenter)

Tags: jquery, animation, dynamic, duration, mouseenter

I made an animation with jQuery with mouseenter/mouseleave and the animate() method on a bunch of div's organized like a hand of playing cards.

When I hover on a div, it's moving 20px up.
everything is going well so far.
But the speed of my animation is linear (50).

What I would like to do is that my animation duration to be equal to the duration of the hover event.

here's my html:

```
<section>
 <div id="one"></div><!--
 --><div id="two"></div><!--
 --><div id="three"></div><!--
 --><div id="four"></div><!--
 --><div id="five"></div><!--
 --><div id="six"></div>
</section>
```

the css:

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
section{
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:400px; 
  height:400px; 
}
div{
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:150px;
    background:black;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
#one{
    z-index:50;
    left:0px;
}
#two{
    z-index:49;
    left:40px;
}
#three{
    z-index:47;
    left:80px;
}
#four{
    z-index:46;
    left:120px;
}
#five{
    z-index:45;
    left:160px;
}
#six{
    z-index:44;
    left:200px;
}
```

and the jQuery :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('div').on({
          mouseenter: function(){
              $(this).animate({
                  'top':'-=20px',
              },50); 
          },
          mouseleave:function(){
              $(this).animate({
                  'top':'+=20px',
              },50);
          }    
      });
  });
```

And the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Tender88/5FKUN/2/

I guess I have to replace the current speed by a variable containing dynamically the duration of the mouseenter event but I have no idea how to retrieve that data :(

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: what is ***the duration of the hover event***?

Comment: But during the hover, you don't know what the duration of the full hover event will be.  If you're trying to start the animation when the hover starts, you can't set an animation to be a duration (of the hover event) that you don't know.  FYI, a `mouseenter` event has no duration.  It occurs at a single point in time.  The `mouseleave` event also occurs at a single point in time.  The duration of the hover can be calculated at the time of the `mouseleave` event if you previously stored the time of the `mouseenter` and then subtract the current time from the previously saved mouseenter time.

Comment: ooops...back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var _steps = {
        "mouseenter": [],
        "mouseleave": [],
        "estimate": [],
        "now": []
    };
    $('div').on({
        mouseenter: function (e) {
            _steps.mouseenter.push(e.timeStamp);
            $(this)
                .animate({
                'top': '-=20px',
            }, {
                duration: 50,
                start: function () {
                    console.log(_steps, _steps.estimate, _steps.now)
                },
                step: function () {
                    _steps.now[0] = $.now();
                }

            })
        },
        mouseleave: function (e) {

            $(this)
                .animate({
                'top': '+=20px',
            }, {
                duration: 50,
                step: function () {
                    _steps.now[0] = $.now();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    // see `_steps` object at console
                    console.log(_steps, _steps.estimate, _steps.now)
                }
            });
            _steps.mouseleave.push(e.timeStamp);
            _steps.estimate[0] = (_steps.mouseleave.slice(-1) - _steps.mouseenter.slice(-1));
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/P5xLh/

Comment: Thanks ! that's exactly what I've been trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your Question Title:**

**[jsBin live demo](http://jsbin.com/joyav/3/edit)**

```
$(function() { // DOM ready shorthand

    var startTime;

    $('div').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
          startTime = new Date().getTime(); 
        },
        mouseleave:function() {
          alert("EVENT DURATION: "+ (new Date().getTime()-startTime) +"ms");
        }
    }); 

});
```

The above will give you the hover duration once you `mouseleave`.

---

If you want to get *live* the duration of a current `mouseenter` an interval should be used:

[**jsBin demo**](http://jsbin.com/joyav/5/edit)

```
$(function() { // DOM ready shorthand

    var duration=0,
            itv,
            ms = 10; //  milliseconds Tick interval

    $('div').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            var el = this;
            itv = setInterval(function(){
                duration += ms;
                $(el).text( duration  );
            }, ms);
        },
        mouseleave:function() {
            clearInterval( itv );
        }
    });

});
```

---

Than a suggestion of mine: **[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/joyav/2/edit)**

```
$('div').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).stop().animate({top: e.type=="mouseenter"?100:150}, 700);
});
```

---

Now let's fast rewind to your question and code

**What you want to achieve with the current code:**

- *animating an element up/down 20px at speed 50ms - repeatedly - as long as the mouse hovers it*

**ISSUE 1**: once the moving element leaves the mouse the registered event will be ˙mouseleave˙.
**ISSUE 2**: Cause of the above mentioned you're forcing the user to follow the element with the cursor :)
**ISSUE 3**: Where should the element stop? ... it goes `top -=20` infinite, right?
**ISSUE 4**: You don't use the `'linear'` parameter for your `.animate()` which means it uses the default `ease`, resulting in a non-linear movement every `+=`or`-=` 20px.
**ISSUE 5**: You're expecting `mouseleave` to do some stuff as long as.... :? Too late.
**ISSUE 6**: *Hover-Time* and *Animation-Duration* are two totally different things. Think about it. If hover time is initially at `0` it'll take exactly `0` to animate to the desired final position. Bam!